# Saving a large turtle graphics image from the entire canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I've been looking around for a few hours, and I couldn't find any solutions for this specific problem. I did see one person who asked the same question, but they didn't provide code, and so didn't get an answer. My problem is this:

I have a program that sends the turtle left and right randomly for a set number of turns. The turning part works, but when I try to save the canvas, it only saves the visible part, which often cuts things off. I have tried increasing the size of the setup canvas, as well as the screen capture, but the saved file always ends up in the top left corner, and so gets cut off. I'm attaching my entire program (it's short, don't worry), because I'm not sure exactly what aspect needs to change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import turtle
import random

'''
Takes a variable, number, of how many random turns the turtle should make and a variable filenumber, 
which is used to save multiple different iterations of the program per program execution
'''

def left_or_right(number,filenumber):

    # Counters to make sure the turtle doesn't turn too many times
    count = 0
    subright = 0
    subleft = 0

    #sets up screen
    win_width, win_height, bg_color = 10000, 10000,'white'
    turtle.setup()
    turtle.screensize(win_width, win_height,bg_color)

    # Clears the screen, sets the turtle in the middle of the screen, drops the pen and hides the
    # Turtle. If you want to see the turtles do the drawing, turn turtle.tracer to True, and
    # uncomment out turtle.speed('fastest')

    turtle.clear()
    turtle.home()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.tracer(False)

    # A for loop for the turtle's turns
    for i in range(number):
        # Calls decider to you can get a random direction every time
        decider = random.randint(0, 1)
        # in order to minimize the turtle just going around in circles,
        # if the turtle has made more that 3 of the same turn, turn it the other way
        # the next to if statements deal with the turtle turning right too many times
        if decider == 1 and subright <= 3:
            turtle.right(90)
            turtle.forward(20)
            count += 1
            subright += 1

        elif decider == 1 and subright > 3:
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(20)
            count += 1
            subright = 0

        # The next two if statements make sure the turtle doesn't turn right too many times
        elif decider == 0 and subleft <= 3:
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(20)
            count += 1
            subleft += 1

        elif decider == 0 and subleft > 3:
            turtle.right(90)
            turtle.forward(20)
            count += 1
            subleft = 0

    # if the number of turns is equal to what the user inputed, stop making the turns
    # and update the screen
    if count == number:
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.update()

    # Take a screen capture of the screen and saves it to where the python file is
    ts = turtle.getscreen()
    ts.getcanvas().postscript(file=filenumber,height=10000, width=10000)

    # turtle.done() is here as a debugging tool. If you set the number of files you're
    # generating to one, you can keep the turtle window open to check that the file correctly
    # copied the turtle screen
    #turtle.done()


''' Takes a variable, filenumber, which is the number of generated files you want'''

def filegen(filenumber):

    for i in range(filenumber):
        # Calls the left or right function as many times as you told it to
        # Note: this is where the left or right function get's its turn number parameters
        left_or_right(10000,i)

def main():

    # calls filegen as many times as you want it to
    filegen(4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```